# How to visualize point cloud colors in Blender 4.0 after PLY data import?

Tags: color, vertex-colors, point-clouds

Given the following data set which stems from the export of a photogrammetric scan:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 28182405          
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
end_header
1.799052 -12.315076 152.604066 114 110 83
1.980052 -12.459076 152.613066 80 87 54
1.836052 -12.331076 152.600066 122 112 87
2.041052 -12.358076 152.613066 86 90 57
1.937052 -12.312076 152.605066 99 96 63
1.976052 -12.453076 152.613066 83 88 56
1.969052 -12.464076 152.613066 81 88 57
1.885052 -12.342076 152.599066 155 141 115
...
```

I can import this data into Blender 4.0 using the `Stanford PLY` importer. I then have a point cloud visible:

[image: Point cloud in Blender - black points]

Checking the [source code of the importer](https://github.com/blender/blender/commit/43e9c90061fc1ebae46a2780f932c64a0f615e78#diff-c700c3293c5d212f7767e72b75edd66fdda6f03fc5d9d9793e2dccb18295ef4cR82) I am pretty sure that the `red`/`green`/`blue` color values were imported into Blender, too:

```
/* Vertex colors */
if (has_color) {
  float4 colors4;
  colors4.x = std::stof(value_vec[color_index.x]) / 255.0f;
  colors4.y = std::stof(value_vec[color_index.y]) / 255.0f;
  colors4.z = std::stof(value_vec[color_index.z]) / 255.0f;
  if (has_alpha) {
    colors4.w = std::stof(value_vec[alpha_index]) / 255.0f;
  }
  else {
    colors4.w = 1.0f;
  }

  data.vertex_colors.append(colors4);
}
```

I then tried to play around with the shaders, yet with no success.

[image]

I may have misunderstood some of the hints I found for older versions of Blender. Also [the docs do not reveal any procedure on how to visualize the color](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/point_cloud.html). Any hint appreciated.

Update in reaction to Blunder's question: The spreadsheet in the Geometry Nodes editor looks like this:

[image]

Update 2: Using Blunder's proposal from below I still seem to miss something:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the *Object Data Properties* tab > *[Attributes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#custom-attributes)* section? Or the spreadsheet in the Geometry Nodes editor?

Comment: The spreadsheet has the data. I update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import your PLY file, you get a mesh with a lot of vertices, each of them with a vertex color (*Col* attribute). Technically, it's not a *Point Cloud* but a *Mesh* object with only vertices. Since this mesh has no faces, nothing is rendered = no color.

[image: screenshot of shader and GN modifier]

With a *Geometry Nodes* (GN) modifier and a *Mesh To Points* node you can convert the mesh into a point cloud. It's recommended to **use *Cycles* to render point clouds** because it can render point clouds natively and does not require geometry. The points will always be rendered as spheres. The *radius* attribute defines the size. You can define this value in the *Mesh To Points* node (see also *Set Radius* node).

Then create a material that uses the *Col* attribute as you did and set this material in the GN modifier. Make sure you set *Viewport Shading* (<kbd>Z</kbd>) to *Rendered* and the render engine to ***Cycles***. The points are not visible in the *Material Preview* shading mode because this mode uses the Eevee render engine.

The render engine ***Eevee* cannot render points directly and needs geometry**. (As of the time this was written, Blender 4.0 was the current version. Perhaps Eevee will be able to do this in future versions of Blender.) - You could instantiate a low-poly object like a cube with 8 verts on the points to see them in the viewport and Eevee renders, but you also need to realize the geometry for the color (see *Realize Instances* node). But don't do this! Because you have over 28 million points you would end up with over 8 * 28 = 224 million vertices!

Comment: One step further: The modifier works. Do I have to add material to the points somehow to obtain PointMaterial? In my settings the "Material" of the original data was proposed but with that one modified via attributes I see no effect. I miss something here.

Comment: I updated my question adding a screenshot of me following your advice. I may have missed something crucial.

Comment: OMG! That is the solution! Could you please add that little information to your answer I will then mark it as solution. Many, many thanks!

Comment: Marked as solution, anyway.

Comment: Nice to read that it worked for you. I have added my comment to the answer and hopefully, it is now clearer that you need *Cycles* to see the points.